# hyperbola: equation for tangent lines and normal lines

Tags: conic-sections

Find the equations for
(a) the tangent lines, and
(b) the normal lines,
to the hyperbola
$y^2/4 - x^2/2 = 1$ when $x = 4$.

Comment: i used the x^2/a^a- y^2/b^2, but its kinda conflicting the initial equation given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=4, \frac{y^2}4=1+\frac{4^2}2=9\implies y=\pm6$

Using Article 305 of [this](http://archive.org/details/elementsofcoordi00lone), the tangent of $$\frac{y^2}4-\frac{x^2}2=1$$
at $(h,k)$  is $$ \frac{y\cdot k}4-\frac{x\cdot h}2=1$$

Do you know how to find the perpendicular of a given line from a given point $(4,\pm 6)$?

Comment: that is from y=6 n x=4?

Comment: @precious, from $(4,6)$ and from $(4,-6)$

Comment: is the equation for the tangent line will be same as above where i substitute the values for x n y ryt?

Comment: @precious, sorry, I could not understand the last part

Comment: help me understand please. i need to write out the equation for the tangent line n the normal line

Comment: @precious, we need replace $(h,k)$ with $(4,6)$ and $(4,-6)$ one by one

Comment: thats gonna give me a positive n negative equation. is this equation 4 the tangent then?

Comment: please what is the equation for the tangent line?

Comment: $$\frac{y\cdot 6}4-\frac{x\cdot 4}2=1$$ and $$\frac{y\cdot (-6)}4-\frac{x\cdot 4}2=1$$. Please simplify

Comment: iv figured it ou....thanks alot @lab bhattacharjee...=

Comment: please what will the normal line to these points be?

Comment: @precious, the gradient of $$\frac{y\cdot 6}4-\frac{x\cdot 4}2=1\iff y=\frac43x+\frac23 $$ is $\frac43$. So, the gradient of the normal is $\frac{-1}{\frac43}=-\frac34$

So, the equation of the normal which passes through  $(4,6)$ will be $$\frac{y-6}{x-4}=-\frac34$$